# Difference between jquery bind

Tags: jquery

Friends, are there any differences between the following snippet codes?

```
  $('.has-child > a').on("click", function() {
                $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle('fast');
                var classname = $(this).find("i").attr('class');
                $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa fa-minus-square").toggleClass("fa fa-plus-square");
            });
```

and

```
 $('.nav-tree').on('click', '.has-child > a', function() {
                $(this).parent().find("ul").slideToggle('fast');
                var classname = $(this).find("i").attr('class');
                $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa fa-minus-square").toggleClass("fa fa-plus-square");
            });
```

what's the differences? Appreciate if you could help me out. thanks.

> $('.has-child > a').on("click", function()

and

> $('.nav-tree').on('click', '.has-child > a', function()

Comment: The second one has means the given selector in the second parameter needs to be contained in `.nav-tree`.

Comment: second one click is delegated to `'.nav-tree'` `Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.`

Comment: Besides, the father-child relationships, any other difference, thanks.

Comment: @guradio thanks. you means the click is happened on .nav-tree, however for the 1st way, the click is happened on .has-child->a, am i right?

Comment: @Guradio, thanks a lot for your wonderful answer.

Comment: The first only binds to `.has-child > a` elements that are in the DOM when you call `.on()`. The second will fire on elements that are added dynamically later.

Answer (score 1):

The first selector tells you that in the complete DOM, find all the **direct children** of class `has-child` which are of type `a` and bind the click handler on them.

The second selector tells you the the same as above. But instead of searching the complete DOM, it only searches inside the DOM elements marked with `nav-tree` class.

Also, binding such a handler to the parent allows events to be attached to elements which are still not mounted in the DOM.